# joda time formatter parsing yyyy-mm-dd with extra hour

Tags: java, jodatime

I'm using Joda time DateTimeFormatter to create a new datetime object in yyyy-mm-dd string format. When calling DateTime date = formatter.parse(String) I get a DateTime object with an extra hour. I live in UTC +1. How to format a string datetime without hours added.

```
 String date = "2013-01-28";

 DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-mm-dd");
 DateTime date = formatter.parseDateTime(date);
 date.ToString() = 2013-01-28T00:01:00.000+01:00
 expected = 2013-01-28T00:00:00.000+01:00
```

Additionally, later in the code I compare two DateTime objects. This parser is in yymmdd format and it does not add one hour.

```
String date = "130102"

 DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyMMdd");
 DateTime datetime = format.parseDateTime(date);
 datetime.toString = 2013-01-02T00:00:00.000+01:00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yyyy-mm-dd uses the **minute-of-hour,** not the month (pattern symbol M). Please refer to the documentation of [pattern symbols on Joda-Time-page](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html).

Parsing "2013-01-28" with your wrong pattern yields "2013-01-28T00:01:00.000+01:00". Do you see the minute equal to 1? And the month of January seems to be a default value if the parser cannot find a month information (in my opinion not smart).

Comment: This was the correct answer. While Orest provided something that worked, you pointed out the error.

Comment: @CraigSmith Well, `formatter.parseLocalDate(date)` only seems to work because parsing to plain date ignores the minute - and chooses the January as default for missing month. It is just by accident that here the default is in agreement with the part in input ("01") at the place where you expected the month but had specified the minute by pattern.